# jquery submit not working inside the fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, grails, fancybox, gsp

I am using jquery fancybox 3 to show a pop-up box.There is a form inside that pop-up which has the icon to download a pdf. On clicking the pdf icon, a function is called which submits the form using jquery. The problem is that it is not submitting(i.e. not going to the specified action set inside the form tag hence not downloading the pdf). My code is as below -

```
<div class = "fancybox3.0_authorizationNoteSummary">
  <g:fancyBoxHeader heading="Authorization Note Summary"/>
    <g:form name="authorizationNoteSummary" action="export" method="post">
    <div style="padding-left: 820px">
        <a class="pdf" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="exportToPdfNoteSummary();"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<div class="gridWrapper">
    <jqgrid:wrapper id="grid2"/>
</div>

    <g:hiddenField name="format" value="pdf"/>
    <g:hiddenField name="authorizationId" value="${params?.authorizationId}"/>
    <g:hiddenField name="authorizationType" value="${params?.authorizationType}"/>
    <g:hiddenField name="sidx" id = "sortBy"/>
    <g:hiddenField name="sord" id = "sortOrder" />
</g:form>
</div>

function exportToPdfNoteSummary(){
      console.log(" export ");
      $('#authorizationNoteSummary').submit();
      console.log("after export ");
}
```

Comment: there is no form with id `authorizationNoteSummary` on your code

Comment: 1) Is your code working outside fancybox? 2) Did you check console for any message? (hit F12 and look at console tab)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add form ID because of `$('#authorizationNoteSummary')` like this :

```
<g:form id="authorizationNoteSummary" name="authorizationNoteSummary" action="export" method="post">
```

Comment: why do you use `<a>` to submit instead of `<g:actionSubmit>` ?